# ActionCable periodic function called on delay * number of users - is this correct?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I have an ActionCable implementation where I want to broadcast the number of users in the channel periodically.

We have the `periodically` function allow this to happen so in my channel definition I have:

```
periodically :broadcast_users, every: 20.seconds
```

but when I view as a subscriber to the channel I appear to get the notification every 20 seconds for each subscribed user, e.g. with 8 users subscribed I get the update 8 times when I log the message on the console:

```
[Log] {active_users: 8, timestamp: "2020-07-24T19:41:31+01:00"} (application-f27a340538c9c0804ff3897eddd5ce90b3846e28f4b2a488dc5e9767b07764bf.js, line 1)
[Log] {active_users: 8, timestamp: "2020-07-24T19:41:31+01:00"} (application-f27a340538c9c0804ff3897eddd5ce90b3846e28f4b2a488dc5e9767b07764bf.js, line 1)
[Log] {active_users: 8, timestamp: "2020-07-24T19:41:32+01:00"} (application-f27a340538c9c0804ff3897eddd5ce90b3846e28f4b2a488dc5e9767b07764bf.js, line 1)
[Log] {active_users: 8, timestamp: "2020-07-24T19:41:32+01:00"} (application-f27a340538c9c0804ff3897eddd5ce90b3846e28f4b2a488dc5e9767b07764bf.js, line 1)
[Log] {active_users: 8, timestamp: "2020-07-24T19:41:32+01:00"} (application-f27a340538c9c0804ff3897eddd5ce90b3846e28f4b2a488dc5e9767b07764bf.js, line 1)
[Log] {active_users: 8, timestamp: "2020-07-24T19:41:33+01:00"} (application-f27a340538c9c0804ff3897eddd5ce90b3846e28f4b2a488dc5e9767b07764bf.js, line 1)
[Log] {active_users: 8, timestamp: "2020-07-24T19:41:33+01:00"} (application-f27a340538c9c0804ff3897eddd5ce90b3846e28f4b2a488dc5e9767b07764bf.js, line 1)
[Log] {active_users: 8, timestamp: "2020-07-24T19:41:33+01:00"} (application-f27a340538c9c0804ff3897eddd5ce90b3846e28f4b2a488dc5e9767b07764bf.js, line 1)
```

The documentation doesn't state this very clearly but is it correct it will broadcast this periodically for every user? e.g. every 20.seconds, once per subscriber?

Just checking if this is expected behaviour and if so is there a way to set a periodic function that doesn't call per subscribed user so only happens once.